# Rails ActiveStorage - accessing through Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

***ActiveStorage*** creates 2 tables `active_storage_blobs` and `active_storage_attachments`.  I wonder if there is a way to access them easily through Rails console (i.e. schema migration internal table can be accessed by `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration`)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sub>Rails is open source, fwiw.</sub>

[Looks like](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/ef5902a2f195c2be5a4e9ad0f31003774a93aa1c/activestorage/app/models/active_storage) it’d be [`ActiveStorage::Blob`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5902a2f195c2be5a4e9ad0f31003774a93aa1c/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L16) and [`ActiveStorage::Attachment`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5902a2f195c2be5a4e9ad0f31003774a93aa1c/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb#L9).